# How to modify selenium ide and deploy

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide

I am coming from java background. Selenium IDE is recorder and playback chrome extension. It is written in javascript. I want to make some changes to selenium IDE say add some more features and deploy it in chrome extension.
How do I go about it?. It is interpreted language. Should I install some plugin for javascript in eclipse? and then prepare a chrome extension file and deploy it in chrome add-ons by dragging like what I did after downloading the selenium IDE extension.

Please provide some starting points. Thanks!.